# Modal in chakra ui not working twice (react)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I used [this](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/modal/usage#usage) document to create modal. it's working fine in first time that I call open button but when I close modal, open button not working again. Do you have any idea?

```
import { useDisclosure, Button, Modal, ModalOverlay, ModalContent, ModalHeader, ModalCloseButton, ModalBody, ModalFooter, Center } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import React from 'react'

export default function Register() {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose, onToggle } = useDisclosure()
  return (
    <Center height={500}>
        <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open Modal</Button>

        <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
          <ModalOverlay />
          <ModalContent>
            <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
            <ModalCloseButton />
            <ModalBody>
              test
            </ModalBody>

            <ModalFooter>
              <Button colorScheme='blue' mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
                Close
              </Button>
              <Button variant='ghost'>Secondary Action</Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </ModalContent>
        </Modal>
    </Center>
  )
}
```

Comment: I copied your code it's working completely correct.
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-keller-upf9mr?file=/src/App.js),
can you explain more

Comment: problem was from StrictMode

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `StrictMode` tag in `app.tsx` file and now it's work fine.

```
 <React.StrictMode> </React.StrictMode>
```

it should be like this:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);
root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ChakraProvider>
    </Provider>
)
```